# windows com datatype bstr, variants, safe array implementation in linux

Tags: c++, linux, com, type-conversion

i have a c++ program written in windows that i'm looking to port to Linux. the program is over a million lines using various com datatype like bstr, variant, and safe array.

i want to know if there is an implementation of these specific datatypes in Linux. i'm aware of WineHQ but i'm looking for guidance on these specific datatypes.

Comment: The only thing I know is that the basic COM idea of the IUnknown interface has been used in a number of component libraries. Including Mozilla XPCOM, and the binary layout of Java Native Interface, and something component in a *nix-world GUI shell. And I think OpenOffice also. So just look around.